# How to generate a python exception with full stacktrace / details?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I want to capture and log (not print) an exception, my current approach is to raise and catch at the same time:

```py
try:
    raise MyException("Ops!")
except MyException as e:
    do_stuff(e)
```

The reason why I am not simply calling `do_stuff(MyException("..."))` is because I need a full stacktrace associated with when it happened.

Is there a more "pythonic" way to do that like `do_stuff(raised MyException("..."))`?

**Extra examples**:

```py
# @Bloodbee (comments) -- this will not work, no stacktrace 
e = Exception("Ops")
logger.exception(e)
```

--

I did my searching around but my results are around generating a stacktrace by itself (using `traceback`) or preserving stacktraces (`raise ... from ...`), both are not what I am looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked logging system from python ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: @Bloodbee I am quite familiar with the logging system, but I may have missed something. Any particular use in mind? I know how to log a raised exception there, but I would still need to raise it first.

Comment: When you catch your exception, use logging.exception(e) ? It will normally display more informations.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.7 you can instantiate your own traceback objects, with no need to have an exception being raised

Comment: "but my results are around generating a stacktrace by itself (using traceback)" I don't understand why this does not solve the problem.

Comment: That's a good point @KarlKnechtel -- my initial mindset is really closed into getting an exception with a traceback, mostly because most of the subsystems for logging, saving and dispatching notifications just takes an exception as parameter. I don't monitor microservices but I export exceptions data. I could refactor the system a bit to use an error message + traceback or even injecting the traceback into the exception -- but the extra work for rare usage probably easier to keep raise+catch one place -- it is not a bad work-around, I just wondered if there was an easier way to do it.